# Create a near real time DWH with Pentaho Community edition

Tags: ssis, pentaho, data-warehouse, real-time-data

I had been exploring best possible ETL tools for extracting data from Oracle and loading it to SQL Server.(initial load approximate 200GB data/20-25 oracle tables) We already have SSIS licence but we had been exploring better options. We have to create a near real time data warehouse(loading every 5 minutes or less). Can we achieve it using Pentaho Community Edition or we need to buy the enterprise edition?

We can also explore other better options apart from Pentaho and SSIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a job in pentaho community edition and schedule it for every 5 minutes execution to refresh your data,in linux machine then you can achieve this using cronjob,windows machine you can do this using windows task scheduler.

Comment: I confirm this answer. And while no marketing guy from Pentaho/Hitachi is looking around: the difference between the PDI/CE and PDI/EE is not significant. Unless of course, you want to  to use Pentaho as a BI platform to publish your reports and dashboards, which does not seam to be your case.